# why am I not exiting the while loop after I enter a $

Tags: java, while-loop

When I enter a $ I would expect that the while loop is exited, but it continues looping.  thank you for your help

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String oneLine = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader indata = new
                    BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while (!oneLine.equals("$")) {

                oneLine = indata.readLine();
                System.out.println(oneLine);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error --" + e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("outside of while \n");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You try and see whether a `BufferedReader` is equal to a `String`; what do you think happens?

Comment: Part 2 of the question.   If i enter $abc I want to exit while loop.  As long as the first character is $ I want to exit.   thank you.

Comment: for that you can do `while(oneLine.charAt(0) != '$')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to that:

```
String oneLine = "";
while ( !oneLine.equals ("$") && oneLine != null){
   oneLine = indata.readLine();
   System.out.println(oneLine); 
}
```

You were comparing a BufferedReader object with a String. I believe you want to compare wiht the current line instead. Also as mentioned in the comments - you need to initialize `oneLine` to a non-null value in order to avoid the `NullPointerException` when you enter the while loop for the first time.

Comment: `oneLine` is not guaranteed to be initialized when the loop condition is checked.

Comment: You have the problem that the line can be null if there is no more data to read